# Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Feature with Id 'guid' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope.

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Since I have to activate Sharepoint Site Collection Feature programmatically, I have added FeatureEventReceiver to the solution. Here is my code,

```
public override void FeatureInstalled(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) {

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://itcdev33"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {

                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                Guid myid = new Guid("32529c03-833d-4c5e-a15e-0bcb35bdedad");
                if (site.Features[myid] == null)
                {
                    site.Features.Add(myid, true, SPFeatureDefinitionScope.Site);
                }
                web.Update();
                site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved, it is not possible to activate same feature in its feature installed event, when the feature is installed. So I used the method known as feature stapling, which works and feature is installed when the solution is deployed.